# Trying to use Webex from webex.com on Firefox 4?

Tags: 10.10, firefox, java, 64-bit, webex

I have previously seen webex working with firefox 3 on the same install of ubuntu,
I have the sun java6 packages installed including the plugin for mozilla.

(sun-java6-bin sun-java6-jre sun-java6-plugin)

I do not have any of the icedtea packages or openjdk packages installed.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steve P found the answer:
https://linuxsagas.wordpress.com/2010/03/05/webex-working-again-in-ubuntu-9-10-64bit/#comment-340

basically:

1. get 32 bit swiftfox 3.6 deb for intel prescott and install: http://getswiftfox.com/download.htm
2. get 32 bit java jre from http://www.java.com/ and install in ~
3. link the appropriate plugin files from the java folder to /usr/lib/swiftfox/plugins

/usr/lib/swiftfox/plugins/libjavaplugin_nscp_gcc29.so -> ~/java32/lib/i386/libjavaplugin_nscp_gcc29.so

/usr/lib/swiftfox/plugins/libjavaplugin_oji.so -> ~/java32/plugin/i386/ns7-gcc29/libjavaplugin_oji.so

/usr/lib/swiftfox/plugins/libnpjp2.so -> ~/java32/lib/i386/libnpjp2.so